# Trying to append to an element using js?

Tags: javascript, dom, innerhtml

I am trying to add to all `<object>`'s on a page a snippet of html. I understand I can access elements by tag name and that I can change the element, but can I simple append to it instead?

In addition, I want to add it to the contents of each  tag, not the end of the document. Which of these methods will work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming no library...

```
var elementToAppend = document.createElement(tagName); // Your tag name here

// Set attributes and properties on elementToAppend here with
// elementToAppend.attribute = value (eg elementToAppend.id = "some_id")
// You can then append child text and elements with DOM methods
// (createElement or createTextNode with appendChild)
// or with innerHTML (elementToAppend.innerHTML = "some html string")

var objects = document.getElementsByTagName('object');
for(var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    elementToAppend = elementToAppend.cloneNode(true);
    objects[i].appendChild(elementToAppend);
}
```

Using `innerHTML` or `outerHTML` as other answers have suggested will likely cause problems for whatever you've embedded with `<object>`.

Comment: so when i set the attributes, how would I set what I want to add?
Like elementToAppend = <html here> ? Thanks!

Comment: +1 for an example showing how to use `appendChild()`. Also good you demonstrated `cloneNode()`. My early attempts to do this assumed you could append the same child node multiple times, with not-so-successful results.

Comment: @patricksweeney: If what you want to append is complex, you have to built it up using `appendChild` as well: `var elementToAppend = document.createElement('span'); var bold = document.createElement('b'); var text = document.createTextNode('stuff'); bold.appendChild(text); elementToAppend.appendChild(bold);`

Answer (score 0):

[appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.appendChild) is what you're looking for.

Comment: I know about appendChild, but wont that add to the end of the document? I want to append it to every occurance of <object>.

Comment: nope, it appends to whatever element you call the function on.