# changing param value of object in html using ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am building a small web application to run midi files. Currently I am using quick time to play the midi files. The problem is that I do not know to what source I need to tie the object until the user enters some information (something like a search ). I need to be able to update the quicktime movie to the correct path. Is it possible? Does ajax support this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AJAX is a technique. What you want to do is to change the QuickTime Movie path with JavaScript.

```
var qtMovie=document.getElementById('yourMovieEmbedID');
qtMovie.src='your new source';
```

You should wrap this code in a function and run it when the user clicks on the OK button.

Comment: Yes, but won't I need to force the page to reload in order for me to listen to the correct source?

Comment: No, JavaScript is dynamic. The changes apply immediately.

Comment: ok, this doesn't seem to work =[
When putting this value:
function SetSource(newSource) {
    document.midiFilePlayer.src = newSource
    alert('new source ' + document.midiFilePlayer.src);
}

the src value does not update.

Comment: Try using .setAttribute('src', 'new source');

Comment: I see, it does seem to update the value, though it doesn't completely solve the problem, I can't seem to update the src value of the embed part, this is the problmatic part of the quick time plug-in code:
  
<embed src="myMidiLocation" width="160" height="120"
  name="midiFilePlayer" autoplay="false" controller="false" enablejavascript="true"
pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/"/>

Answer (score 0):

If you actually need to *add* a `<param>` (as opposed to adjusting an attribute value), I've discovered that grabbing the `<object>`, cloning it, adding the `<param>` and then replacing the current `<object>` tag seems to work in most browsers (although it doesn't seem to work in Firefox). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168494/how-do-i-programmatically-set-all-objects-to-have-the-wmode-set-to-opaque/1173723#1173723) for a working example.

That linked answer is for every `<object>` on a page, here is how you would do it for a single instance of the tag:

```
// create the appropriate <param>
var elementToAppend = document.createElement('param');
elementToAppend.setAttribute('name', 'src');
elementToAppend.setAttribute('value', 'blah.midi');
// get a reference to the <object>
var obj = document.getElementById('yourMidiPlayerObject');
// duplicate the <object>
var newObj = obj.cloneNode(true);
// append the <param> to the <object>
newObj.appendChild(elementToAppend);
// replace the <object> on the page
obj.parentNode.replaceChild(newObj, obj);
```

If the `<param>` you want to modify already exists things are a bit different:

```
// get a reference to the <object>
var obj = document.getElementById('yourMidiPlayerObject');
// duplicate the <object>
var newObj = obj.cloneNode(true);
// get a reference to the current <param>
var param = document.getElementById('theParamId');
// duplicate the <param>
var newParam = param.cloneNode(true);
// change the value of the <param>
newParam.setAttribute('value', 'newblah.midi');
// replace the <param> tag on the <object>
newObj.replaceChild(newParam, param);
// replace the <object> on the page
obj.parentNode.replaceChild(newObj, obj);
```

In both cases, the trick to getting it working in IE, Opera, Safari and Chrome is to replace the `<object>` on the page. Appending a new `<param>` to the existing `<object>` doesn't seem to make it reparse the value or load the newly referred to content.