# Flash ad comming over a javascript popup

Tags: javascript, html, flash, ads

i am using jquery based facebox popup. My ad platform is Doubleclick. Some flash ad comes over the popup. I am loading the ad's js code in a iframe.

I tried passing wmode=transparent to as a parameter to the js ad code i did help for some flash ads but to some ads it's not taking wmode=transprent. I even tried to increase z-index of facebox but that too didn't help. What can i do .

I dont think so this could be a double clik specfic problem( i know its where i have to look for help) but a flash of other site over my text/content issue

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you don't have control over the flash ad/javascript ad tags coming from the agency adverts. The only universal solution I have found to this problem is to use what ever callbacks are available for your popup plugin and hide the adverts when the popup loads, then show them again then the popup closes.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to pass wmode=transparent to the JS. You have to pass it to Flash.
[More information at Adobe Flash's Website.](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14201.html)

Comment: wmode=transparent is passed to the doubleclik ad code which generates/displays the flash

Answer (score 0):

Hiding the ads when showing the popup is a possible solution discussed in this thread:

[Flash on top of jQuery dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515939/flash-on-top-of-jquery-dialog/)

Questions similar to this one comes up on a regular basis here at SO and I don't know of any one solution that works in all browsers and all applications.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used facebox popup but am sure it would have some outer div right, just give that dive some solid color via css eg background-color:#ccc and it will come over flash even if its wmode is window.