# Why popup window is under embedded objects

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, popupwindow

I am writing code to open popup window in greasemonkey using div. Everything is fine, but when window is opened on pages with embedded objects, it is not obove the objects. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

If the embedded object is a Flash player then set the object param to opaque.

```
<object ...>
    <param name="wmode" value="opaque">
</object>
```

Also see [How do I programmatically set all <object>'s to have the wmode set to opaque?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168494/how-do-i-programmatically-set-all-objects-to-have-the-wmode-set-to-opaque) to see how to do it automatically.